# ROS and Android with Kinetic and Android Studio

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to get ROS (Kinetic) and Android working together in Android Studio. I followed the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment

I created a new project, edited the gradle files but I get this error when I try to build the app and I cannot find anything about this.

```
Error:Android tasks have already been created.
This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
continue configuring the model.
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273664/ros-and-android-with-kinetic-and-android-studio/) by [TristanKpka](https://answers.ros.org/users/30075/tristankpka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-10-20**:
Hello! Could you please specify at what point you got that error?

**Comment by [TristanKpka](https://answers.ros.org/users/30075/tristankpka/) on 2017-10-20**:
I got that error when I build the app. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of placing the `ros-android` plugin in the bottom level Gradle file, leave the bottom level as is. Just add `android_10` to the dependencies and remove the `espresso` from `AndroidTestCompile`.

Your bottom level script should look like something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.androidrostest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_10:[0.3,0.4)'    // Added dependency!!!
}
```

In your top-level script, replace the buildscript as the tutorial indicates:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/raw/kinetic/buildscript.gradle"
}
```

And add the following:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'ros-android'

    afterEvaluate { project ->
        android {
            // Exclude a few files that are duplicated across our dependencies and
            // prevent packaging Android applications.
            packagingOptions {
                exclude "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
                exclude "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you might need to remove the `android:icon` from the manifest or indicate to replace it with another one, as `android_10` already provides a default.

Let me know if it worked. If it does, I will update the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TristanKpka](https://answers.ros.org/users/30075/tristankpka/) on 2017-10-23**:
Thank you. I added your code plus `tools:node="replace"` in the manifest. I am compiling a project that needs dependencies.

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-10-23**:
Cool!
Tutorial updated: http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment